# Runnable jar connects to sqlite but exe of the same doesn't

Tags: java, sqlite, jar

I have created a runnable jar file for a login page. The folder where the runnable jar is saved also contains a folder named "lib" which contains files for images (used for icons and stuff) and an sqlite database file (which contains usernames and passwords).

When I execute the runnable jar and click on the login button after entering the username and password, it successfully executes. But when I convert the same jar file to exe and run it, the images from lib folder get loaded, but nothing happens when I click the login button. It seems as if the exe file is not connecting to the sqlite database in the "lib" folder.

Following is the code:

```
package db;

import javax.swing.*;

public class One extends JFrame {

    private JButton btn_login = new JButton("LOGIN");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField tf_user;
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    private JPasswordField tf_pass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        One frameTabel = new One();
    }

    One(){
        super("LOGIN PAGE");
        setTitle("NETWORK TRACKER - LOGIN");
        setBackground(new Color(70, 130, 180));
        btn_login.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 8));
        btn_login.setBackground(new Color(102, 205, 170));
        btn_login.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btn_login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try{
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:lib/login.sqlite");
                    String sql = "SELECT * from table12 where Username=? and Password=?";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1, tf_user.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, tf_pass.getText());
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    if(rs.next()){
                        rs.close();
                        pst.close();
                        setVisible(false);
                        Display dp = new Display();
                        dp.setVisible(true);
                        dp.setSize(300, 300);
                    } else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password is not correct");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: "+e);
                } finally{
                    try{
                        rs.close();
                        pst.close();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btn_login.setBounds(342,153,58,20);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(112, 128, 144));

        panel.add(btn_login);

        setupLog();
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel lbl_title = new JLabel("NETWORK TRACKER LOGIN PAGE    ");
        lbl_title.setBackground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
        lbl_title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lbl_title.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        lbl_title.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lbl_title.setBounds(0, 252, 457, 23);
        panel.add(lbl_title);

        JLabel lbl_user = new JLabel("USERNAME");
        lbl_user.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lbl_user.setForeground(new Color(255, 250, 250));
        lbl_user.setBounds(263, 93, 69, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_user);

        tf_user = new JTextField();
        tf_user.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        tf_user.setBounds(342, 90, 105, 22);
        panel.add(tf_user);
        tf_user.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lbl_pass = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
        lbl_pass.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lbl_pass.setForeground(new Color(255, 250, 250));
        lbl_pass.setBounds(263, 129, 69, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_pass);

        tf_pass = new JPasswordField();
        tf_pass.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        tf_pass.setBounds(342, 123, 105, 20);
        panel.add(tf_pass);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");

        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("lib/login.png"));
        label.setBounds(0, 11, 236, 240);
        panel.add(label);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setupLog(){
        setSize(473,313);
        setLocation(500,280);
        panel.setLayout (null);
    }
}
```